# I am having a bit of a strange error on mysql pdo. How can I solve it?

Tags: php, mysql

In my profile table I want to insert some data and my profile table structure look likes

```
  CREATE TABLE Profile (
  profile_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 first_name TEXT,
 last_name TEXT,
 email TEXT,
 headline TEXT,
 summary TEXT,

 PRIMARY KEY(profile_id),

 CONSTRAINT profile_ibfk_2
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users (user_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the position table look like

```
  CREATE TABLE Position (
  position_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  profile_id INTEGER,
  rank INTEGER,
  year INTEGER,
  description TEXT,

  PRIMARY KEY(position_id),

    CONSTRAINT position_ibfk_1
    FOREIGN KEY (profile_id)
    REFERENCES Profile (profile_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is my insert query:

```
           $insert = $con->prepare("insert into 
            profile(user_id,first_name,last_name,email,headline,summary)
                
         
        values(:user_id,:firstName,:lastName,:email,:headline,:summary)");
                
                $insert->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
                $insert->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName);
                $insert->bindParam(':lastName', $lastName);
                $insert->bindParam(':email', $email);
                $insert->bindParam(':headline', $headline);
                $insert->bindParam(':summary', $summary);
                //Now need to execute the operation
               // $insert->execute();
                $profile_id=$con->lastInsertId();

                //insert to position
                $rank=1;
                for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++){
                    if(! isset($_POST['year'.$i])) continue;
                    if(! isset($_POST['desc'.$i])) continue;
                    $insert = $con->prepare("insert into position 
                    (profile_id,rank,year,description)
                     values(:profile_id,:rank,:year,:desc)");
                    //Here we need to bind those variable for storing 
                    value into the database
                    $insert->bindParam(':profile_id', $profile_id);
                    $insert->bindParam(':rank', $rank);
                    $insert->bindParam(':year', $_POST['year'.$i]);
                    $insert->bindParam(':desc', $_POST['desc'.$i]);

                    //Now need to execute the operation
                    $rank++;
                 //   $insert->execute();

                }
                if($insert->execute()){
                    $_SESSION['profile_addition'] = 'Profile added';
                    header("location:index.php");
                }
                else{
                    print_r($insert->errorInfo());
                }
```

In these insert queries, I wanted to try insert into two tables at the same time when a user would click to the add button.
Now my problem is: When I want to insert data into the profile and position table. It gives an error. Here is the error

```
    Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1452 [2] => Cannot add or update a child 
    row: a foreign key constraint fails (`courseraassignment`.`position`, 
    CONSTRAINT `position_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profile` (`profile_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) )
```

So, now my question is: What is the problem in my code? If you can then please assist me to get the solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your profile record get inserted?  What is the value in `$profile_id`?

Comment: `//Now need to execute the operation` - and did we actually? Or did we leave `// $insert->execute();` commented out, which would mean we did not actually create a profile first after all …?

Comment: No sir. @NigelRen

Comment: Sir, I made the execution under the if block.@CBroe

Comment: You will need to change back to running the `execute()` statements at each point.  You will not get the auto increment id until you have inserted the profile record.  If you want to ensure all are created or nothing is created - have a look at transactions.

Comment: Ok sir, Now I am going to try. Thank you. @NigelRen

Comment: Sir, My problem has been solved. Your suggestion works. Thank you a million.@NigelRen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code , you should execute query before getting last insertid , and also you should execute queries inside loop not outside

```
$insert = $con->prepare("insert into 
profile(user_id,first_name,last_name,email,headline,summary)


values(:user_id,:firstName,:lastName,:email,:headline,:summary)");

$insert->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$insert->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName);
$insert->bindParam(':lastName', $lastName);
$insert->bindParam(':email', $email);
$insert->bindParam(':headline', $headline);
$insert->bindParam(':summary', $summary);
//Now need to execute the operation
$insert->execute(); // uncomment this execute
$profile_id=$con->lastInsertId();

//insert to position
$rank=1;
$checker = false ;
for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++){
    if(! isset($_POST['year'.$i])) continue;
    if(! isset($_POST['desc'.$i])) continue;
    $insert = $con->prepare("insert into position 
    (profile_id,rank,year,description)
     values(:profile_id,:rank,:year,:desc)");
    //Here we need to bind those variable for storing 
    value into the database
    $insert->bindParam(':profile_id', $profile_id);
    $insert->bindParam(':rank', $rank);
    $insert->bindParam(':year', $lastName);
    $insert->bindParam(':desc', $email);

    //Now need to execute the operation inside loop 
    $rank++;
    if($insert->execute()){
        $checker = true ;
    }

}
// here you can't check execute 
if( $checker){
    $_SESSION['profile_addition'] = 'Profile added';
    header("location:index.php");
}
else{
    print_r($insert->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got your solution. @Akram Elhaddad